# i create project in angular 6 using angular cli tool but it gives error import * as fs from 'fs';

Tags: angular6

i create project in angular 6 using angular cli tool but it gives error when i **import * as fs from 'fs'**(integrate electron app). The error message **Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using node.

Are you using webpack? If so see
[here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/447)

The solution is to add

```
node: {
   fs: 'empty'
}
```

to your webpack config.

If that doesn't work, try changing your import statement to a require:
`const fs = require('fs');`, as the node documentation recommends.